# problem printing value retrieved from MySQL Query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I am trying to print a value retrieved from a MySQL query with javascript. Here is the code

```
function editVal(category){

            //alert(category);
            //document.getElementById("editdiv").innerHTML = '<input type = text value='+category+'>';
            <?

                $tagquery = mysql_query("Select latitude from Zones where tag = 'category'");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tagquery)) { ?>
                  alert(category);
                  document.getElementById("editdiv").innerHTML = '<input type="text" value='"+<?=$row['latitude']?>+"'/>'; 
                <?}?>    
        }
```

I know the query is working fine as I tested it before in a different form. But for some strange reason this snippet is not entering into the while loop (I tried to find it with alert function). You can have a look of the page here - http://128.233.104.33/gameview/mapv.php

I know it might be good if I would used a web service but for now just trying to solve this problem.

Any help please?

Comment: Can't you just output the HTML using PHP, instead of using JavaScript for this? Intermingling JS with PHP is generally not a good idea and usually a sign of bad coding practice, let alone you're making it more cumbersome to change your code afterwards. BTW, usability experts recommend placing check boxes *before* the item names, not after them.

Comment: OMG ... I can do that.. Trying it!

Comment: What html/js does this render out as?

Comment: @zeb - You can anything you want with programing, but this is generally discourage. One of the biggest consequence will be google search engine rank, as google chose to ignore javascript

Comment: Thanks for the your valuable suggestions. Tried to follow that and replace the snippet with - <?
                    
                    $tagquery = mysql_query("Select latitude from Zones where tag = 'category'");
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tagquery)) {
                        echo '<input type="text" value="', $row['latitude'], '"/>';
                    }?> ......... Unofrutnately not working :(

Comment: @zeb - what is not working ? be precise, and keep update your question to make it clearer ...

Comment: I meant to say I tried to put it in echo instead of using javascript in between but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make an AJAX call if you want to execute a mysql query with some parameter (here `category`) in query condition which depends on what you clicked.

Try to understand that, server side code has finished executing and then you clicked on the checkboxes. At this instant client side code is running and even a correct mysql query cannot run if you put it here.

Your query would actually run while the page is being generated by the server, and at that time it would not get the value of `category` and hence would run with `category` = '', hence not entering the while loop.